# Android OpenGL ES onFrameAvailable were not called?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I use OpenGL ES for playing a video, just use Android MediaPlayer.
It works. But just only it was running last few seconds.
then onFrameAvailable method were not called anymore,
and I just only can heard voice of video.

```
  public void onDrawFrame(GL10 paramGL10)
   {
    synchronized (this) {

            if (this.updateSurface)
            {

                this.mSurface.updateTexImage();
                this.mSurface.getTransformMatrix(this.mSTMatrix);
                this.updateSurface = false;
            }
     } 
     myDraw();
   }

    public void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture paramSurfaceTexture)
    {
      this.updateSurface = true;
      requestRender();   
    }
```

How should I do?

Comment: Looks like you're decoding video onto a SurfaceTexture, then rendering the texture onto a GLSurfaceView? Sounds like your problem is with the video decode, not the GLES part. Can you add more details about the video decoding to the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener stops being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185661/surfacetexture-onframeavailablelistener-stops-being-called)

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like your problem is what's described in [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15864444).

Basically, there's a pool of buffers available to the SurfaceTexture. Whenever `onFrameAvailable()` is called, one of those buffers is taken from the pool and to put it back in you need to call `updateTexImage()`.
Now, it might happen that `onFrameAvailable()` is called multiple times between two calls to `onDrawFrame()`. In that case, multiple buffers are allocated from the pool, but only one is put back in (because `updateTexImage()` is still only called once). This can lead to a situation where no more buffers can be allocated and the calls to `onFrameAvailable()` stop.

The solution proposed in the linked answer is to replace the boolean flag with an integer count and call `updateTexImage()` the required number of times.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with VideoSurfaceView example. I deleted line

```
setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
```

and it helped me

Answer (score -1):

This is likely a threading issue. As the two calls are on separate thread. So your updateSurface variable can be set to false before right after being set to true without an updateTexImage call which would cause this to hang.

You can fix the race condition by updateSurface being ref counted. (You are also missing the synchronize call in onFrameAvailable.)

```
private int updateSurface = 0;

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 paramGL10)
   {
    synchronized (this) {

            if (this.updateSurface)
            {

                this.mSurface.updateTexImage();
                this.mSurface.getTransformMatrix(this.mSTMatrix);
                this.updateSurface--;
            }
     } 
     myDraw();
   }

    public void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture paramSurfaceTexture)
    {
      synchronized (this) {
          this.updateSurface++;
          requestRender();   
      }
    }
```