# Android - Encode a video while decoding it

Tags: android, video, opengl-es-2.0, android-mediacodec, video-encoding

I modify a video with glsl shaders, using a SurfaceTexture and OpenGL ES 2.0. I can also encode the result video with MediaCodec.

The problem is that the only way I've found to decode the video is with MediaPlayer and SurfaceTexture, but MediaPlayer doesn't have a frame by frame decoding option. So right now, it's like a live encoding/decoding, there is no pause.

I've also tried to use seekTo / pause / start, but it would never update the texture..

So would it be possible to do a step by step decoding instead, to follow the encoding process ? I'm afraid that my current method is not very accurate.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, instead of using MediaPlayer, you need to use MediaExtractor and MediaCodec to decode it (into the same SurfaceTexture that you're already using with MediaPlayer).

An example of this would be ExtractMpegFramesTest at http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/, possibly also DecodeEditEncodeTest (or for a >= Android 5.0 async version of it, see https://github.com/mstorsjo/android-decodeencodetest).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I thought MediaPlayer was sufficient but apparently the stream speed is not controlable, so it cannot be synced with the encoder.. The problem is that ExtractMpegFramesTest might be too slow, DecodeEditEncodeTest example does not use a video file as input but custom "VideoChunks" so it's a bit hard for me to understand. And I need to have min api 18 so.. Some help would be very appreciated, thanks !

Comment: Managed to do it based on ExtractMpegFramesTest.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : Wrong, mediaPlayer's stream cannot be used frame by frame, seems like it only works in "real" speed.

I've managed to do it with MediaPlayer actually. Following this answer :

[stackoverflow - SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener stops being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185661/surfacetexture-onframeavailablelistener-stops-being-called)

Using counters, you can speed up or speed down the video stream, and synchronize it with the preview or the encoding.

But - If you want to do a real seek to a particular frame, then mstorsjo's solution is way better. In my case, I just wanted to make sure the encoding process is not going faster or slower than the video input stream.